# Pyqt save dom to file

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4, qwebpage

Why this code does not work ?
I want save dom after js execute at this page and i want use qt without gui.
Sorry for my English.

```
#coding:utf-8
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtWebKit


class Sp():
    def save(self):
        print "call"
        data = self.webView.page().currentFrame().documentElement().toInnerXml()
        open("htm","w").write(data)
    def main(self):
        self.webView = QtWebKit.QWebPage()
        self.webView.load(QtCore.QUrl("http://www.google.com"))
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.webView,QtCore.SIGNAL("loadFinished(bool)"),self.save)
s = Sp()
s.main()
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a QApplication before executing other stuff.

Add this:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
s = Sp()
s.main()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**UPDATED**: Also, change the code, because QWebPage doesn't have a *load* method:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWebKit

class Sp():
    def save(self):
        print "call"
        data = self.webView.page().currentFrame().documentElement().toInnerXml()
        open("htm","w").write(data)
        print 'finished'
    def main(self):
        self.webView = QtWebKit.QWebView()
        self.webView.load(QtCore.QUrl("http://www.google.com"))
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.webView,QtCore.SIGNAL("loadFinished(bool)"),self.save)

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
s = Sp()
s.main()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: thx, How i can open the html file locally? Without downloading

Comment: You can use setHtml: *void QWebView::setHtml (const QString & html, const QUrl & baseUrl = QUrl())*

Comment: At the end of the save function, add this line: `sys.exit(0)`.